# How do I obtain the Laurent series for $f(z)=\frac 1{\cos(z^4)-1}$ about $0$?

Tags: complex-analysis, convergence-divergence, power-series, taylor-expansion

I know that $$\cos(z^4)-1=-\frac{z^8}{2!}+\frac{z^{16}}{4!}+...$$ but how do I take the reciprocal of this series (please do not use little-o notation)? Or are there better methods to obtain the required series?

Comment: A [follow-up](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/333645/what-is-the-order-of-this-pole)? Still working on this function? Is this homework?

Comment: @julien Hi Julien! I decided to create a new question because I feel it deserves its own answer. No, it's not homework. If you don't mind to elaborate on the little-O notation usage in the original question, I'd love to read it.

Comment: Hi Ryan. Definitely, the full Laurent series is a different question which deserves its own answer. O and o are useful in many situations. To begin with limit determination. It allows you to keep the relevant part in a Taylor expansion and to throw away the remainder. Unlike equivalents, O's and o's can be safely added, subtracted, etc...

Comment: The reciprocal doesn't help you a lot and I don't see a nice system [here](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Series%5B1%2F%28Cos%5Bx%5E4%5D+-+1%29%2C+%7Bx%2C+0%2C+80%7D%5D)

Comment: @DominicMichaelis How do you mean by not seeing a nice system? And do you mean that the way to obtain the Laurent series isn't by taking the reciprocal as I suggested? If so, then how can I produce the Laurent series?

Comment: Long division...

Comment: @Ryan I think the reciprocal doesn't help you to find the full taylor series. My first idea would be leipnizformula to get all derivatives but to be honest I guess you won't find  an explicit formula (to be more honest I didn't even try after calculating the first 10 derivatives with mathematica the terms got about 100 times to long for me)

Comment: @DominicMichaelis Hey, did you mean for finding the residue at 0 instead? If so, yes, it's crazy to take derivatives. For this particular problem, to find the resiude at 0 (which is an order-8 pole), long division  (though I'm still not comfortable with long division involving infinite series) to first obtain the Laurent series seems to be the best method.

Comment: @Ryan no i mean for the Laurentseries $$\sum_{n=-8}^\infty a_n z^n $$ the long division won't work well

Comment: Isn't the series explicit from the formula? Why need to perform division?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Long Division ... still worth learning

[image]

To get more terms in the quotient, use more terms in the divisor.

Comment: Thank you. While I understand the mechanics of the above division, I am unsure why it works, because for polynomial long division I'm accustomed to listing the polynomials in decreasing instead of increasing powers. I also don't know how the radius of convergence of a Laurent series obtained by division is related to that of the original Taylor series (in this case, the series in the denominator).

Comment: That doesn't help you to get the full laurent series, and when you wan't another term you have to calculate all, I see no advantage to making the taylor series by taking derivates often

Comment: @DominicMichaelis What derivatives?

Comment: @Ryan, you get the coefficients of the laurent series for $n>$ with $$a_n=\frac{f^{(n)}}{n!}$$ just like the taylor series.

Comment: And you think computing the 8th derivative of $f(z)$ is easier than the long-division calculation above?

Answer (score 1):

Of course the easy way is to ask a CAS.  This is from Maple:

$$
(-2)   z^{(-8)} - \frac{1}{6} - \frac{1}{120}   z^{8} - \frac{1}{3024}   z^{16} - \frac{1}{86400}   z^{24} - \frac{1}{2661120}   z^{32} -  \\
\quad{}\quad{}\frac{691}{59439744000}   z^{40} - \frac{1}{2874009600}   z^{48} - \frac{3617}{355687428096000}   z^{56} -  \\
\quad{}\quad{}\frac{43867}{150267476975616000}   z^{64} - \frac{174611}{21127833228902400000}   z^{72} -  \\
\quad{}\quad{}\frac{77683}{335740477128376320000}   z^{80} - \frac{236364091}{36822263841994427596800000}   z^{88}
 \\
\quad{}\quad{} - \frac{657931}{3722690410399436636160000}   z^{96} + \operatorname{O} \bigl(z^{104}\bigr)
$$

Answer (score 1):

The function $f(z)=\frac1{\cos(z^4)-1}$ can be rearranged as
\begin{align*}
f(z)&=-\frac1{1-\cos(z^4)}\\
&=-\frac{1}{2\sin^2\frac{z^4}2}\\
&=-\frac12\biggl(\frac{2}{z^4}\biggr)^2 \Biggl(\frac{\frac{z^4}{2}}{\sin\frac{z^4}{2}}\Biggr)^2\\
&=-\frac{2}{z^8} \Biggl\{1+\sum_{q=1}^{\infty}(-1)^q\Biggl[\sum_{k=1}^{2q}\frac{(2)_k}{k!}
\sum_{j=1}^k(-1)^j\binom{k}{j} \frac{T(2q+j,j)}{\binom{2q+j}{j}}\Biggr]\frac{z^{8q}}{(2q)!}\Biggr\},\quad z^4<2\pi,
\end{align*}
where $(2)_k$ is the Pochhammer symbol or the rising factorial and $T(2q+j,j)$ denotes the central factorial numbers of the second kind. The last step comes from employing Theorem 4.1 in the paper

1. Feng Qi and Peter Taylor, *Series expansions for powers of sinc function and closed-form expressions for specific partial Bell polynomials*, Applicable Analysis and Discrete Mathematics **18** (2024), no. 1, in press; available online at https://doi.org/10.48550/arXiv.2204.05612.

Comment: Another answer is at https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4672268

Answer (score 1):

From
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}\label{sin-square-recip-ser}
\biggl(\frac{x}{\sin x}\biggr)^2&=1+2B_2x^2-4\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}(-1)^k\Biggl[\bigl(2^{2k-1}-1\bigr)B_{2k}\\
&\quad-\sum_{j=1}^{k-1}\binom{2k}{2j}\bigl(2^{2j-1}-1\bigr)\bigl(2^{2k-2j-1}-1\bigr)B_{2j}B_{2k-2j}\Biggr]\frac{x^{2k}}{(2k)!}\\
&=1+\frac{x^2}{3}+\frac{x^4}{15}+\frac{2 x^6}{189}+\frac{x^8}{675}+\frac{2 x^{10}}{10395}+\frac{1382 x^{12}}{58046625}+\dotsm
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
for $x\in(-\pi,\pi)$, we can arrive at
\begin{align*}
\frac1{\cos(z^4)-1}&=-\frac12\biggl(\frac2{z^4}\biggr)^2\Biggl(\frac{\frac{z^4}2}{\sin\frac{z^4}2}\Biggr)^2\\
&=-\frac2{z^8} \Biggl\{1+\frac{B_2}2z^8-4\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}(-1)^k\Biggl[\bigl(2^{2k-1}-1\bigr)B_{2k}\\
&\quad-\sum_{j=1}^{k-1}\binom{2k}{2j}\bigl(2^{2j-1}-1\bigr)\bigl(2^{2k-2j-1}-1\bigr)B_{2j}B_{2k-2j}\Biggr]\frac{z^{8k}}{2^{2k}(2k)!}\Biggr\}
\end{align*}
for $z^4\in\bigl(-2\pi,2\pi\bigr)$.

References

1. Xue-Yan Chen, Lan Wu, Dongkyu Lim, and Feng Qi, *Two identities and closed-form formulas for the Bernoulli numbers in terms of central factorial numbers of the second kind*, Demonstratio Mathematica **55** (2022), no. 1, 822--830; available online at https://doi.org/10.1515/dema-2022-0166.

Comment: The power series of the function $\frac1{2\cos x-1}$ is at https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4672327

Comment: Perhaps mention that the $B_k$s are the Bernoulli numbers.