# Finding coefficients of laurent series for $\frac 1{1-\cos z}$ about zero

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series, laurent-series

I know I'm wrong, but I fail to see why I'm wrong. My goal is to try and find the terms for the Laurent series of $f(z)=\frac{1}{1-\cos(z)}$ but I'm surely off.

$$\begin{align} f(z)&= \frac{1}{1-\cos(z)}
\\ &= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \cos(z)^n
\\ &= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \left( \sum_{j=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^jz^{2j}}{(2j)!}\right)^n
\end{align}$$

Under nothing that I wrote, can $z$ have a negative exponent. However, it is obvious that it should, both by looking at the function and checking my intuition over at [Wolfram Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=laurent+series+1%2F%281-cos%28z%29%29).

Where is my reasoning wrong?

Comment: You only have $$\frac{1}{1-q} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty q^n$$ if $\lvert q\rvert < 1$. But in every neighbourhood of $0$, there are $z$ with $\lvert \cos z\rvert > 1$.

Comment: Wow, that's painfully obvious. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As this is a second order pole, you only need consider $\sum_{n=-2}^{\infty} a_{n}z^{n}$. Now, check the limits of $[z^3\cdot f(z)]''/2!$ and $[z^2\cdot f(z)]'/1!$ as $z \rightarrow 0$ and we get $1/2$ and $0$ respectively. Then, evaluate $\lim\; 1/(1-\cos(z)) - 2/z^2 \rightarrow \frac{(1/4!)}{(1/2!)} = 1/6$ as $z \rightarrow 0$. This is as many terms as I went. But there is no noticeable pattern as far as I can see at a first glance.

Comment: Just to confirm, the reason we take these limits is because the nth coefficient of the laurent series is given by $\frac{1}{2\pi i}\oint\frac{f(z)dz}{z^{n+1}}$ which equals the residue of $f(z)$ at $z=0$ which equals the nth derivative of $\lim_{z\to0}\left( f(z)*z^{n+1}\right)/n!$... correct?

Answer (score 1):

The comments have explained why your proposal doesn't work, and leads to nonsense like a constant term of $\sum_{n=0}^\infty (1)^n = \infty$.

When $z\approx 0$, we have $\cos z = 1 - \frac{z^2}2 + \frac{z^4}{4!} - \dots$, and so 
$$ \frac1{1-\cos z} = \frac1{\frac{z^2}2 - \frac{z^4}{4!} + \dots} = 2z^{-2} \left(1 - \sum_{j\geq 1} \frac{2(-z^2)^j}{(2j)!} \right)^{-1} = 2z^{-2} \sum_{n\geq 0} \left( \sum_{j\geq 1} \frac{2(-z^2)^j}{(2j)!} \right)^n$$
I don't see a particularly snazzy way to say what this generating function counts.

Answer (score 1):

By definition of cosine $$\frac{1}{1-\cos z}=\frac{-2e^{iz}}{(e^{iz}-1)^2}\tag1$$
On the other hand $\frac{t}{e^t-1}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{B_n}{n!}t^n$ gives
$$\frac{-2e^t}{(e^t-1)^2}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{2(n-1)B_n}{n!}t^{n-2}\tag2$$
From $(1),(2)$
$$\frac{1}{1-\cos z}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{\frac n2+1}2(n-1)B_{n}}{n!}z^{n-2}$$
Due to $(1-1)B_1=0$ and the fact that other odd indexed Bernoulli numbers vanish, letting $n=2k$ we have
$$\frac{1}{1-\cos z}=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^{k+1}2(2k-1)B_{2k}}{(2k)!}z^{2k-2}$$

Answer (score 0):

My answer is
\begin{multline*}
\frac{1}{1-\cos x}=\frac{1}{2\sin^2\frac{x}{2}}
=\frac12\biggl(\frac{2}{x}\biggr)^2\Biggl(\frac{\frac{x}2}{\sin\frac{x}2}\Biggr)^2
=\frac{2}{x^2} \Biggl\{1+\\
\sum_{q=1}^{\infty}(-1)^q\Biggl[\sum_{k=1}^{2q}\frac{(2)_k}{k!} \sum_{j=1}^k(-1)^j\binom{k}{j} \sum_{m=0}^{2q}(-1)^{m}\binom{2q}{m} \biggl(\frac{j}{2}\biggr)^{m} \frac{S(2q+j-m,j)} {\binom{2q+j-m}{j}}\Biggr]\frac{x^{2q}}{(2q)!}\Biggr\},
\end{multline*}
where $|x|<2\pi$ and $S(2q+j-m,j)$ denotes the Stirling numbers of the second kind. The last step comes from employing Theorem 4.1 in the paper

1. Feng Qi and Peter Taylor, *Series expansions for powers of sinc function and closed-form expressions for specific partial Bell polynomials*, Applicable Analysis and Discrete Mathematics **18** (2024), no. 1, in press; available online at https://doi.org/10.48550/arXiv.2204.05612.

Comment: Another answer is at https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4672242

Answer (score 0):

From
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}\label{sin-square-recip-ser}
\biggl(\frac{x}{\sin x}\biggr)^2&=1+2B_2x^2-4\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}(-1)^k\Biggl[\bigl(2^{2k-1}-1\bigr)B_{2k}\\
&\quad-\sum_{j=1}^{k-1}\binom{2k}{2j}\bigl(2^{2j-1}-1\bigr)\bigl(2^{2k-2j-1}-1\bigr)B_{2j}B_{2k-2j}\Biggr]\frac{x^{2k}}{(2k)!}\\
&=1+\frac{x^2}{3}+\frac{x^4}{15}+\frac{2 x^6}{189}+\frac{x^8}{675}+\frac{2 x^{10}}{10395}+\frac{1382 x^{12}}{58046625}+\dotsm
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
for $x\in(-\pi,\pi)$, we acquire
\begin{align*}
\frac1{1-\cos x}&=\frac12\biggl(\frac2x\biggr)^2\Biggl(\frac{\frac{x}2}{\sin\frac{x}2}\Biggr)^2\\
&=\frac12\biggl(\frac2x\biggr)^2\Biggl\{1+\frac{B_2}{2}x^2-4\sum_{k=2}^{\infty}(-1)^k\Biggl[\bigl(2^{2k-1}-1\bigr)B_{2k}\\
&\quad-\sum_{j=1}^{k-1}\binom{2k}{2j}\bigl(2^{2j-1}-1\bigr)\bigl(2^{2k-2j-1}-1\bigr)B_{2j}B_{2k-2j}\Biggr]\frac{x^{2k}}{2^{2k}(2k)!}\Biggr\}
\end{align*}
for $x\in(-2\pi,2\pi)$.

References

1. Xue-Yan Chen, Lan Wu, Dongkyu Lim, and Feng Qi, *Two identities and closed-form formulas for the Bernoulli numbers in terms of central factorial numbers of the second kind*, Demonstratio Mathematica **55** (2022), no. 1, 822--830; available online at https://doi.org/10.1515/dema-2022-0166.

Comment: The power series of the function $\frac1{2\cos x-1}$ is at https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4672327