# What is the Taylor series of $\frac{1}{\sin(z)}$ about $z_0 = 1$?

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series, laurent-series, trigonometric-series

This was a exam question so I know it cannot take too long to write out the proof. Only I cannot see an answer.

I would imagine you write $\sin(z) = \sin(1+(z-1)) = \sin(1)\cos(z-1) + \sin(z-1)\cos(1)$ and then use the everywhere-defined Taylor series for $\sin$ and $\cos$ to write $\frac{1}{\sin(z)}$ as the reciprocal of a power series. Then you manipulate it into the form $\displaystyle \frac{1}{1-P(z)}$ where $P$ is a power series and then invert using the geometric series formula. Only my $P$ looks horrible and thus the condition for convergence $|P(z)|<1$ is impossible to compute.

Another series which I cannot do but which I imagine could be done by similar methods is $\displaystyle \frac{1}{2\cos(z) -1}$ about $z_0 = 0$.

Any tips?

Answer (score 2):

Using the Taylor series expansion for $\csc(x)=\frac{1}{\sin(x)}$, we may write write $$\frac{1}{\sin(z)}=\csc(z)=\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\csc^{(k)}(1)\frac{(z-1)^{k}}{k!}.$$ This series will have radius of convergence $1$ since the poles of $\csc(x)$ are precisely at the the zeros of $\sin(x)$, all of which occur at integer multiples of $\pi$.

Now, this might not be satisfying at all, but this is likely the best that you can do. Ideally we would want to specify the coefficients $\csc^{(k)}(1)$ exactly  (by giving a power series expansion we are doing precisely that) however they are extremely messy. The only way I can think of writing them without derivatives involves the Bernoulli numbers and powers of $\sin$ and $\cos$ evaluated at $1$.

Answer (score 2):

The function $z\mapsto 1/\sin(z)$ is meromorphic and has simple poles at points of $\pi\Bbb{Z}$. Thus it has a power series expansion $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n(z-1)^n$ 
around $z_0=1$, with radius of convergence $R=d(1,\pi\Bbb{Z})=1$.
Now to determine the coefficients we may can use the identity
$1=\sin(z)\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n(z-1)^n\right)$ 
in the neighborhood of $z_0=1$. Or, by setting $z=1+t$:
$$
\left(\sin(1)\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{(2k)!}t^{2k}
+\cos(1)\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^k}{(2k+1)!}t^{2k+1}\right)
\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n t^n\right)=1
$$
So, the coefficients $\{a_n\}$ may be obtained inductively by the formula 
$$\eqalign{
a_0&=\frac{1}{\sin(1)},\cr
a_n&=-\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{(-1)^{\lfloor k/2\rfloor}}{k!}\delta_ka_{n-k},\
}
$$
where $\delta_k=\left\{
\matrix{\cot(1)&\hbox{if $k$ is odd,}\phantom{z}\cr
1&\hbox{if $k$ is even.}}
\right.$

Answer (score 0):

By the Faa di Bruno formula and some properties of the Bell polynomials of the second kind, we acquire
\begin{align*}
\biggl(\frac1{\sin z}\biggr)^{(n)}
&=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{(-1)^kk!}{\sin^{k+1}z} B_{n,k}\biggl(\cos z,-\sin z,-\cos z,\sin z,\dotsc, \sin\biggl[z+\frac{(n-k+1)\pi}{2}\biggr]\biggr)\\
&=\frac{1}{\sin z}\sum_{k=0}^n \sum_{\ell=0}^k\frac{\binom{k}{\ell}}{(2\sin z)^{\ell}} \sum_{q=0}^\ell(-1)^q\binom{\ell}{q}(2q-\ell)^n \cos\biggl[(2q-\ell)z+\frac{(n-\ell)\pi}2\biggr]\\
&\to\sum_{k=0}^n \sum_{\ell=0}^k\frac{\binom{k}{\ell}}{2^\ell(\sin1)^{\ell+1}} \sum_{q=0}^\ell(-1)^q\binom{\ell}{q}(2q-\ell)^n \cos\biggl[2q-\ell+\frac{(n-\ell)\pi}2\biggr], \quad z\to1
\end{align*}
and
\begin{gather*}
\biggl(\frac{1}{2\cos z-1}\biggr)^{(n)}
=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{(-1)^kk!}{(2\cos z-1)^{k+1}} 2^k B_{n,k}\biggl(-\sin z,-\cos z,\sin z,\cos z,\dotsc, \cos\biggl[z+\frac{(n-k+1)\pi}{2}\biggr]\biggr)\\
=\sum_{k=0}^n\frac{2^k\cos^kz}{(2\cos z-1)^{k+1}} \sum_{\ell=0}^k\binom{k}{\ell}\frac{(-1)^\ell}{(2\cos z)^\ell}
\sum_{q=0}^\ell\binom{\ell}{q}(2q-\ell)^n \cos\biggl[(2q-\ell)z+\frac{n\pi}2\biggr]\\
\to\cos\frac{n\pi}2 \sum_{k=0}^n 2^k \sum_{\ell=0}^k\frac{(-1)^\ell}{2^\ell} \binom{k}{\ell} \sum_{q=0}^\ell\binom{\ell}{q}(2q-\ell)^n, \quad z\to0\\
=\begin{cases}\displaystyle
(-1)^m\sum_{k=0}^{2m} 2^k \sum_{\ell=0}^k\frac{(-1)^\ell}{2^\ell} \binom{k}{\ell} \sum_{q=0}^\ell\binom{\ell}{q}(2q-\ell)^{2m} & n=2m\\
0, & n=2m+1
\end{cases}
\end{gather*}
for $m,n\ge0$. Therefore, we have
\begin{multline*}
\frac1{\sin z}=\frac1{\sin1}+\sum_{n=1}^\infty\Biggl\{\sum_{k=0}^n \sum_{\ell=0}^k\frac{\binom{k}{\ell}}{2^\ell(\sin1)^{\ell+1}}\\ \times\sum_{q=0}^\ell(-1)^q\binom{\ell}{q}(2q-\ell)^n \cos\biggl[2q-\ell+\frac{(n-\ell)\pi}2\biggr]\Biggr\}\frac{(z-1)^n}{n!}, \quad |z-1|<1
\end{multline*}
and
\begin{equation*}
\frac{1}{2\cos z-1}
=\sum_{m=0}^\infty(-1)^m\Biggl[\sum_{k=0}^{2m} 2^k \sum_{\ell=0}^k\frac{(-1)^\ell}{2^\ell} \binom{k}{\ell} \sum_{q=0}^\ell\binom{\ell}{q}(2q-\ell)^{2m}\Biggr]\frac{z^{2m}}{(2m)!}, \quad |z|<\frac{\pi}6.
\end{equation*}
All formulas, notations, concepts, and knowledge can be found in the following two papers.

References

1. F. Qi, *Derivatives of tangent function and tangent numbers*, Appl. Math. Comput. **268** (2015), 844--858; available online at https://doi.org/10.1016/j.amc.2015.06.123.
2. Feng Qi, Da-Wei Niu, Dongkyu Lim, and Yong-Hong Yao, *Special values of the Bell polynomials of the second kind for some sequences and functions*, Journal of Mathematical Analysis and Applications **491** (2020), no. 2, Paper No. 124382, 31 pages; available online at https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jmaa.2020.124382.

Comment: The power series expansion of the functions $\frac1{\cos(z^4)-1}$ and $\frac1{1-\cos z}$ were given at https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4672242, https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4672897, https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4672268, and https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4672891.